# Javascript Arrays as an object field

Tags: javascript

I am running into a problem with using an array as a Javascript field.

```
var Object = function () {

  var admins = [];

  this.addAdmin = function(admin){
    this.admins.push(admin)
  }

}
```

Normally I would expect admin to be pushed into the array admins but instead I get a 'cannot read property 'push' of undefined'.

If I'm not mistaken when I initialized the Object with new Object(), admins = []; should initialize the array.  Is this a limitation of Javascript?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't reuse [built-in function names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/Object) for your own functions. It makes for confusing code.

Comment: @pilchard — No. Because the `new` keyword is used, `this` is the same in both those places.

Comment: @Quentin - Well, probably, depending on how `addAdmin` gets called. :-)

Comment: Thank you for all of the answers.  Looks like I was creating a local variable when I didn't intend to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`var array` creates a **local variable**. It does not create a **property** on the object.

You need:

```
this.admins = [];
```

or

```
admins.push(admin) /* without this */
```

Answer (score 2):

In your function `admins` is a local variable to the function. You need to declare `admins` as a property on the instance.

```js
function Obj(){
    this.admins = [];
}
Obj.prototype.addAdmin = function(admin){
    this.admins.push(admin);
}

obj = new Obj();
obj.addAdmin('tester');
```

Also, because `Object` is the global base object, don't create functions or objects named `Object`.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you've gotten confused *(which is easy :-) )* because you've seen code like this:

```
class Obj {
    admins = [];

    addAdmin(admin) {
        this.admins.push(admin);
    }
}
```

That uses the modern `class` and *class fields* syntax to puts an `admins` property on the object constructed via `new Obj`. (Note there's no `var` before `admins = [];`.) But in your code, you've used the older `function`-based syntax. Within your function, `var admins = [];` just creates a local variable, not a property.

I'd suggest that if you want to create constructor functions, using the new `class` syntax above is the simpler, more powerful way to do that. If you want to use the older syntax, though, other answers have shown how, but for completeness either make `admins` a property of the object:

```
let Obj = function() {
    this.admins = []; // ***
  
    this.addAdmin = function(admin){
        this.admins.push(admin)
    };
};
```

or perhaps with `addAdmin` on the `prototype`:

```
let Obj = function() {
  this.admins = []; // ***
};
Obj.prototype.addAdmin = function(admin){
    this.admins.push(admin)
};
```

or use the fact `addAdmins` closes over the call to `Obj`, and thus the local `admins`:

```
let Obj = function() {
    const admins = [];
  
    this.addAdmin = function(admin){
        admins.push(admin) // <=== No `this.` here, you want to close over the
                           // `admins` local
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assumming `Object` is a placeholder, because it is a reserved keyword.

What is happening is, your variable   `var admins = [];` is created locally and can noot be accesed with the this. as a result when you set the value in     `this.admins.push(admin)` the admins there is undefined. you should modify your function to read this way

```js
var Obj = function () {
  this.admins = [];

  this.addAdmin = function (admin) {
    this.admins.push(admin);
  };
};

const object = new Obj();

object.addAdmin(1);
```

you should not omit the this keyword like this(no pun intended) if you plan to new the function. Stick to the code above.

```js
    var Obj = function () {
      var admins = [];

      this.addAdmin = function (admin) {
        admins.push(admin);
      };
    };

    const object = new Obj();

    console.log(object)
```